# Solution to the exponential integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\bigl(-pR-\frac{ER^{-f}}{B}\bigr)dR$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have a exponential integral $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-pR-\frac{ER^{-f}}{B}\right)dR$$ where E, p, B, and f are constants, $E>0$

#### Context

This equation arrives when I try to consider how particles can randomly work from one location to another in arXiv powder bed. I can not find a solution to the integral, but I was told that the solution is $\exp\left( (-CE)^{\frac{1}{1+f}} \right)$.  Could anyone help me how it comes up and what is C? Thank you.

Comment: I have added more context information in my previous post. Please let me know if additional information is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see that $E$ itself is negative... is it?

Comment: sorry, E should be positive. I will make a change.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the case $E=0$.  Then
$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\big(-pR\big)\,dR = \frac{1}{p}
$$
but the proposed "solution" is $\exp(0)=1$.  Not a good sign for the case $E>0$.

Maple will do the case $f=1$:
$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-p R-\frac{ER^{-1}}{B}\right) =
2\sqrt{\frac{E}{Bp}} \mathrm{K}_1\left(2\sqrt{\frac{Ep}{B}}\right)
$$
where $K_1$ is a Bessel function.